# The definition of $SO(p,q)$ only depends on the signature $(p,q)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $q$ be a quadratic form $V\times V \to \mathbb R$ with matrix $Q$ under some basis. By linear algebra, $Q=P^TEP$, where $E$ is the diagonal matrix of with $p$ 1's, $q$ -1's and some zeros. $P$ is an invertible matrix. I wonder if

$$\{A\in M(n,\mathbb R):(Ax)^TQ(Ay)=x^TQy, \forall x,y\}\cong \{A\in M(n,\mathbb R):(Ax)^TE(Ay)=x^TEy, \forall x,y\}$$

so that the definition of $SO(p,q)$ only depends on the signature $(p,q)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $GL(V)$ acts on quadratic forms. Two quadratic forms in the same orbit have conjugate stabilizers. That's the moral of the story.